# How to serialize Angular URL with auxiliary routing?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

Currently what is being happening is, when you navigate to any aux route the URL page will be

> my-url/(router-name:aux)

What I want is, it should be something like

> my-url/router-name/aux

Is this even logical? I don't know if it will contradict with any primary routing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used URLSerializer provided by Angular itself.
You can find the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer).

All we need to do here is parse URL to actual one, and serialize the parsed URL to desired one and both can be achieved via UrlSerializer methods (parse and serialize respectively).